# "git-upload-pack not permitted" error in Oracle SQL developer, but I can clone from GitHub Desktop

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I did clone successfully in Oracle SQL Developer couple months ago. Now I tried to clone again, I got the " git-upload-pack not permitted" error in SQL Developer. But I can still clone in GitHub Desktop. What could cause the clone failed only in SQL Develoer?

Comment: Your Git installation seems to be working fine; your permission to access the repository has been removed / revoked. You'd have to ask the owners of Oracle SQL Developer why that occurred.

Comment: @torek do you mean the config in Oracle SQL Developer caused it?

Comment: No, I mean whoever *owns* the repository. Your Git makes an "internet phone call" (to an ssh or https web site) to obtain new commits from some other Git. That *other Git* decides who it's wiling to talk to. They were willing to talk to you before, and now they're not. You need to figure out why that is the case. Why don't they like you any more?

Comment: If they do like you when you run Github Desktop, but not when you run some other software, you can try to figure out what's different about the way the "phone calls" are made. That might let you sidestep the problem. But, if it used to work both ways, and doesn't now, and you have not changed anything, they must have changed something on *their* end.

Comment: thank you. My permission to access the repository was removed.

Answer (score 0):

A less convenient solution is to open the folder where your .sql file is stored and use GIT Bash to manually push to the remote repository. It works for me